# Подскажите как правильно вычислить значения?

Tags: математика, формулы

есть небольшой обменик валют и вот такие курсы

```
1RUB = 0.0000681LTC
1LTC = 12263.639
```

когда меняем RUB на LTC

```
LTC = 0.0000681 * 1750 = 0.119175
```

когда меняем наоборот LTC на RUB

```
RUB = 0.143 * 12263.639 = 1753.70038RUB
```

!! Но если я меняю опять RUB на LTC:

`LTC = 2100 * 0.0000681 = 0.143LTC` получается когда идет обмен справа налево, то считается неверно

Как правильно высчитать если я меняю 0.143LTC на RUB

я думал тоже перемножить но идет потеря 400RUB

Comment: Читается как бред (сорри). Попробуйте обдумать хорошо свой вопрос и сформулировать его более вменяемо.

Comment: так у вас разные курсы. 400 руб с вас налог за обмен. в банке также баксы продают. купил-продал деньги потерял

Comment: нет, пока что это у меня в базе все лежит, и не могу правильно расчитать если менять LTC на RUB

Comment: Мало что понятно. Что такое 2100? Что такое 1750?

Comment: это сумма в рублях

Comment: Смотрите на ваши курсы: `0.0000681 * 12263.639 == 0.8351538158999999` Ясно, что в результате конвертации туда-обратно получится сумма меньше. Теряется ~16%.

Comment: Ну всё правильно, обменник берёт комиссию ))  Туда-сюда поменял - на комиссии деньги потерял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

Вы меняете

```
1) LTC->RUB: 0.143LTC * 12263.639 = 1753.70038RUB
2) RUB->LTC: 1753.70038RUB * 0.0000681 = 0.119427LTC
```

Получаете разницу

```
0.143LTC - 0.119427LTC = 0.023573LTC
```

При данных курсах все верно.

Чтобы обмен проходил без потерь, Вам нужны курсы, удовлетворяющие условию

```
КурсRUB * КурсLTC = 1
```

---

Пусть `S_L` - сумма в LTC, `S_R` - сумма в RUB.

При обмене туда-обратно имеем систему

```
S_L * КурсLTC = S_R;

S_R * КурсRUB = S_L.
```

Подставим

```
S_R * КурсRUB * КурсLTC = S_R
```

Разделим на S_R

```
КурсRUB * КурсLTC = 1
```

---

Таким образом, при данном курсе RUB

```
1RUB = 0.0000681LTC
```

нужен курс LTC

```
1LTC = 1 / 0.0000681 = 14684.287812RUB
```

Проверим:

```
1) LTC->RUB: 0.143LTC * 14684.287812 = 2099.853157RUB
2) RUB->LTC: 2099.853157RUB * 0.0000681 = 0.143LTC
```